# Liveness & Readiness probes are not working, application is working fine but the probes are failing so the container is restarting

Tags: kubernetes

I'm new to kubernetes and docker, I am trying to resolve this error since weeks with no luck.

I have multiple deployments and some of them are working fine. While others are having connection refused error.

I have tried increasing initialDelaySeconds, timeoutSeconds and all. Application is starting but probes are giving connection refused error. So the container is restarting again and again.

Is there any configuration in dockerfile?

Comment: What does the logs say ?

Comment: Can you please share the yaml file

Comment: Please provide enough code or context so others can better understand or reproduce the problem. Can you share your pod/deployment definition, the application log related to the probes and maybe the pods event?